# Why do chess tournaments allow absolutely scandalous draws?

Tags: draw

I am currently watching the Rapid World Championship and the amount of draws between players is absolutely shocking. I'm not talking about games where each player fights to the end and the game just happens to be a draw - that is perfectly okay in my opinion.

But so many games are being drawn on default - players are simply agreeing to draw far before any sort of endgame is reached. Just now, 5 minutes ago, Anish Giri drew a game after **10 moves**. 10!!!  TEEEEN!!!

Why do chess tournaments allow this scandalous behavior?

Imagine if any other sport was played this way. Imagine if Barcelona and Real Madrid are playing football, and they just decide to leave the pitch after 20 minutes because they no longer want to play, and agree to a draw.

Why is this behavior not banned? Why isn't a rule enforced so that a draw can only be reached after many moves (as was the case in the World Championship with Caruana and Carlsen)?

Answer (score 1):

Anish Giri was likely playing a "solved" opening, one in which all lines have been analyzed to a draw. Also, Giri is **extremely** hard to beat and draws many of his games (his weakness is that he doesn't often win). In this situation, there was likely no room for progress outside of severe blunders, so it's almost a respect issue, where Giri and his opponent respected each other enough to admit that no blunders were likely to be made, especially in this line. This sort of "guaranteed ending" does not occur in games like football or baseball or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Many FIDE tournaments do have a rule where a draw can only be reached after >= 30 moves. If I recall correctly, this rule is quite predominant especially in the closed tournaments which super GMs play in.

I suppose they could also implement the rule in rapid and blitz tournaments, but these events are more informal and less important. The need for so many extra strict rules decreases.

Sports like hockey, football, etc don't allow quick draws since the game could never naturally end early on in a draw. In chess though, the game could easily end (naturally) in a draw.